# Java: execute Runnable fixed number of times

Tags: java, threadpool, scheduledexecutorservice

So I have a piece of code that I want to execute repeatedly. I get this part. The problem is that I want to execute the code at fixed intervals, but only a fixed number (in this case 1440) times.

Any ideas how I'd do that?

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class Simulator {

    public static int TICK = 10;
    public static int NUM_OF_SERVERS = 3;
    public static int LENGTH_OF_SIMULATION = 1440;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        final MultiQueueControlSystem multiController = MultiQueueControlSystem.getInstance();
        final SingleQueueControlSystem singleController = SingleQueueControlSystem.getInstance();

        multiController.generateQueuesAndServers(NUM_OF_SERVERS);
        singleController.generateQueuesAndServers(NUM_OF_SERVERS);

        final ScheduledExecutorService ticker = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        ticker.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

            int currentTime = 0;

            public void run() {

                if(currentTime < LENGTH_OF_SIMULATION) {
                    currentTime = currentTime + 1;
                } else {
                    ticker.shutdown();
                    return;
                }

                multiController.customerArrival();
                multiController.allocateCustomersToServers();
                multiController.removeFinishedCustomersFromServers();

                singleController.customerArrival();
                singleController.allocateCustomersToServers();
                singleController.removeFinishedCustomersFromServers();
            }
        }, 1, TICK, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Comment: `currentTime` is always 0

Comment: @user2418306 Yeah I know. Someone else wrote most of the code. But yeah, that's why I'm asking the question -- it doesn't work! :)

Comment: I'm sorry. Actually `SceduledExecutorService` do preserve state of the `Runnable` at least on my JVM implementation. Code above works for me.

Comment: The above code works for me as well. The currentTime value is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider giving your runnable a reference to the `ScheduledExecutorService`. Then instead of scheduling at a fixed rate, just schedule for future execution. Have the runnable instance keep tracker (through an `AtomicInteger`) how many times it has been executed. When it completes it's normal execution it can schedule itself for future execution. Once it has executed the desired number of times, it would not schedule itself again.

Comment: This is humorous (but angry) commentary on the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://code.nomad-labs.com/2011/12/09/mother-fk-the-scheduledexecutorservice/) and how to get it to behave.  LOL.  Worth a quick glance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

Take any integer variable `runCount` (increment after every cycle) and `service` the object returned from `scheduleAtFixedRate` method

`if(runCount == LENGTH_OF_SIMULATION ) {
     service.cancel(false);
  }`